# Can a policy throw an exception if the result criteria is never met?

Tags: c#, polly

I'd like to use Polly to handle the result of an HTTP API call I need to make.  I have the policy defined as:

```
var r = await Policy
    .HandleResult<DescribeApplicationVersionsResponse>(x => x.ApplicationVersions[0]?.Status != ApplicationVersionStatus.Processed)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(10, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), onRetry: (describeResponse, timeSpan, context) => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Application version was '{describeResponse.Result.ApplicationVersions[0].Status}', retrying in {timeSpan}");
    })
    .ExecuteAsync(() =>
        BeanstalkClient.DescribeApplicationVersionsAsync(describeApplicationVersionRequest)
    );
```

If the policy never succeeds (i.e., the result criteria is never met and the retry limit has been passed) I'd like to throw an exception as my application can't continue.

Is it possible to define that through the Polly policy builder extension methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all retries configured for a Polly retry policy are exhausted without the executed delegate succeeding, the retry policy rethrows the exception for which no more retries are permitted, as documented [in the Polly readme](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) (foot of retry section) and [Polly retry wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works).

---

If you want to throw a different exception from the one propagating from the delegate, you could do any of:

- `try`/`catch` and throw something else; (or)
- use Polly [`.ExecuteAndCapture(...)`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception) to capture, then check, the final execution result, and throw your own custom exception; (or)
- use [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) to wrap a [`FallbackPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) outside the retry policy, and in the FallbackPolicy, handle the exception from retries-failing and in the fallback action, rethrow a different custom exception.

---

**EDITED**: To reflect the fact that the OP's original policy was handling results, not exceptions. An approach using `FallbackPolicy` with `PolicyWrap` could be as follows:

```
var retry = Policy
    .HandleResult<DescribeApplicationVersionsResponse>(x => x.ApplicationVersions[0]?.Status != ApplicationVersionStatus.Processed)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(10, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), onRetry: (describeResponse, timeSpan, context) => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Application version was '{describeResponse.Result.ApplicationVersions[0].Status}', retrying in {timeSpan}");
    });

var fallback = Policy
    .HandleResult<DescribeApplicationVersionsResponse>(x => x.ApplicationVersions[0]?.Status != ApplicationVersionStatus.Processed) // Probably worth factoring the predicate out into a method so that it is only stated once.
    .FallbackAsync(async () => { throw new ReplacementException(); });

var r = await fallback.WrapAsync(retry)
    .ExecuteAsync(() =>
   BeanstalkClient.DescribeApplicationVersionsAsync(describeApplicationVersionRequest)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In this example, I don't have an original exception that I'm handling.  I'm retrying based on an object value only.  Maybe the most straightforward way for me to handle this is to wrap my API call in a function that throws an exception if the response value isn't what I need.  Then I'll get the exception rethrowing for free.

Comment: Ah. Yes, you could wrap your response in an exception at origin. If you want to leave the response as an object value, though, but get Polly to translate the final failed object result into an exception, then you could do that per my third bullet: a `FallbackPolicy`. Outside the retry, you can wrap (with `PolicyWrap`) a `FallbackPolicy` which handles the result, and whose fallback action is to throw your replacement exception.  That way, you could express your overall desired approach as a single Policy (the PolicyWrap, combining the fallback and retry).

Comment: Here is a quick [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BYgLy4) illustrating the approach in my previous comment. It can be easily translated to other return types, and async.

Comment: Edited answer to provide async version based around the originally posted code.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response and example, much appreciated.  This should get me what I was looking for!